# Qual é a origem da expressão "meter o bedelho"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões

Dizemos, “não meta o bedelho onde não é chamado”, ou seja, ‘não se intrometa onde não é chamado’.

> [Dicionário Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/bedelho)
>   **Meter o bedelho (em)**
>   **1** Intrometer-se sem ser chamado (em conversa alheia, discussão etc.)
>
> [Dicionário Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bedelho)
>   **Meter o bedelho**
>   • [Informal]  Fazer ou dizer algo relativamente a alguma coisa ou a alguém que não lhe diz respeito. = INTROMETER-SE

É interessante que a palavra "bedelho" é definida pelos dicionários como tranca ou ferrolho de porta. Assim, não existe uma lógica direta com a expressão.

Qual é a origem da expressão "meter o bedelho"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Bedelho*** é também um trunfo pequeno nos jogos de cartas [(Aulete 3)](http://www.aulete.com.br/bedelho), e creio que foi desta aceção que surgiu a expressão ***meter o bedelho***. Em primeiro lugar, esta aceção parece ser a mais antiga. O primeiro dicionário a incluir a aceção ‘tranqueta’ é o de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899, enquanto que a aceção ‘trunfo pequeno’ e, implicitamente, a expressão *meter o bedelho* já aparecem em 1712 no *Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* de Raphael Bluteau:

[image]

O dicionário de Moraes da Silva de 1789 dá a *bedelho* também o significado figurado de «homem de pouca autoridade», o que está de acordo com a ideia de ‘trunfo pequeno’. Estes significados sugerem uma possível origem para *meter o bedelho*. Se alguém intervém num assunto alheio, mas tiver alguma coisa importante e relevante a dizer, a intromissão será compreendida e até apreciada. Mas intervir num assunto alheio, sem autoridade para o fazer nem nada de importante a contribuir seria como jogar um trunfo pequeno: a sua intervenção teria pouco valor, como um bedelho no jogo de cartas; a pessoa poderia até dar-se mal, por haver outro que tivesse um ‘trunfo maior’.

Esta parece ser a interpretação de *meter o bedelho* no *Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* de Domingo Vieira de 1871:

> BEDELHO, *s. m.* Em jogo de cartas, o trunfo pequeno. — Na locução famíliar, bedelho, homem de pouca autoridade.— *Metter o* **bedelho**, interromper a conversação, com dito que não merece auctoridade.

Esta ideia, que meter o bedelho é intrometer-se sem ter nada de importante a contribuir, transparece também no uso espontâneo (fora de dicionário) mais antigo de ‘meter o bedelho’ que consegui encontrar no Google Books, o poema *O Elefante e o Burro* de [Bocage (1765-1805)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_Maria_Barbosa_du_Bocage) incluído em [*Poesias de Manuel Maria de Barbosa du Bocage*, Tomo III, 1853](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1LYFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA202&dq=bedelho&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv-pXmm5jOAhWGORoKHSzDCPY4wgMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=bedelho&f=false) (ênfase minha):

> O Elephante, e o Burro
>
> No tempo em que inda falavam
>   Os animaes como a gente,
>   É tradição que tiveram
>   Conferencia em caso urgente
>
> O burro, que não sei como
>   Se introduziu no conselho,
>   Quis, fingindo-se estadista,
>   Também **meter seu bedelho**.
>
> Eis n’um tom, que diferia
>   Bem pouco do que hoje é zurro,
>   Foi revolvendo a questão,
>   Discretou como um burro,
>
> Depois de lhe ter ouvido
>   Alguns conceitos de arromba,
>   O carrancudo elephante
>   Lhe disse, torcendo a tromba:
>
> »Esse tempo, que tens gasto
>   Inutilmente em clamar,
>   Insensato, não podias
>   Aproveital-o em pastar?

Comment: Interessante a acepção de "bedelho" como "pessoa de pouca autoridade". Teria alguma relação com "bedel" - que é também alguém de autoridade pequena?

Comment: @Luis Encontrei um dicionário do século XIX que diz isso mesmo. Agora não sei se ele tinha conhecimento de facto, ou fez uma simples conjetura como tu acabaste de fazer. Eu já me tinha lembrado que 'trunfo pequeno' fosse inspirado no bedel. O bedel, entre outras coisas, podia ser um funcionário na Universidade de Coimbra responsável pela disciplina e marcação de faltas. Estou mesmo a ver os estudantes  a inventarem o diminutivo *bedelho* (faz lembrar *fedelho*).

Answer (score 2):

Penso que até tem uma relação bastante directa na medida em que o bedelho (ferrolho da porta) é metido ou enfiado por entre um apertado aro de metal com o objectivo de impedir a abertura da porta, da mesma forma que quem se intromete na conversa alheira se "enfia" figurativamente por entre assuntos apertados que não lhe dizem respeito.

Da mesma forma, o bedelho que impede a abertura indesejada da porta por estranhos, que se intromete na conversa pode involuntariamente impedir a sua natural progressão ou desenvolvimento com a sua intromissão.

Answer (score 1):

Se mantida a acepção de "tranca", então meter o bedelho é interromper, fazer um corte, criar um impasse, o que é sempre questionado pelo status quo por ser, fundamentalmente, um ato de rebeldia.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja por causa do ferrolho ser demasiado grande ou pequeno para o local onde será usado. Então colocar o bedelho errado, vai fazer coisa que não vai funcionar. Dai a expressão meter o bedelho onde não é chamado, é porque vai fazer coisa que não está certa.

Comment: Fernando, bem-vindo ao site. Achei essa ideia curiosa: os ferrolhos que tenho visto têm o tamanho certo; quando não entram é por estarem perros; e *meter o bedelho* na minha experiência não significa que algo não funciona. De qualquer modo isso é apenas uma impressão pessoal; não é grande coisa como explicação da origem da expressão, até porque *bedelho* pode ter tido significados diferentes no passado.